# Loading VisitorIdentification.js causes 404 not found error

Tags: experience-profile, tracking

I am trying to enable VisitorIdentification on our pages, so I have added `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` to our layout pages.  However, when the page loads, it throws a 404 when trying to load VisistorIdentification.js found in /layouts/system/

The file exists, however when I try to browse to it directly, it also throws the file not found error page.  If I put this file in the root /Scripts/ folder, it will load correctly.

The permissions are set so the site can access this folder, and it is using the layouts in the /layouts/ folder, as well as loading the VisitorIdentification.ascx in the /layouts/system folder, however it is not able to find the VisitorIdentification.js file.

This is the only thing that is found in the log file:

`21492 12:09:40 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Path '/layouts/system/VisitorIdentification.js' was not found.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)`

Comment: Do you have any custom 404 handlers that maybe intercepting the request?

Comment: can you post the actual errors from the log ?

Comment: We don't have any custom 404 handlers.  I've added what I found in the log to the question

Comment: Does the `VisitorIdentification.js` presents at the path `Website\layouts\System` and also does the directory has enough read access?

Comment: Can you try adding a .html or other common file type to `/layouts/system` and see if that file returns a 404 as well? Perhaps it's something specific to `.js` files in that folder?

Comment: The VisitorIdentification.js file exists there, as does the VisitorIdentification.ascx file which is loading fine (this file runs some code to load the JS file).  Any type of file that I put in this directory is throwing a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

There was specific web.config in the layouts folder that was generated and had this line in it, which was blocking all files.

`<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />`

Updating this to only block cshtml and ascx files has fixed the issue

`<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml,*.ascx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />`